# What's the difference between window.x and x?

Tags: javascript

Let's say, "x" is a variable that never defined, so it should be undefined. In the following scenario:
1)

```
if(x){//do something}
//ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

2)

```
if(window.x){//do something}
//worked as expected
```

As far as I know, in browser environment here, x should be the same as window.x, could anyone help to point out the reason for the different behavior here?

Comment: You're allow to reference undefined object properties; you're not allowed to use undeclared variables. You must declare your variables (e.g., with `var`) before you can use them, but you do not need to declare object properties before you can use them (they'll just be `undefined` by default).

Answer (score 7):

`x` will only be the same as `window.x` if it was declared (in the global scope, naturally). That can be done with an explicit `var` statement in the global scope, or a simple assignment without `var` in any scope (which is considered an implicit global declaration):

```
var a; // declares global a
function foo() {
    b = 10; // declares (implict) global b
}
```

Both `a` and `b` will also be available as `window.a` and `window.b` in web browsers.

This also creates a global variable on browsers:

```
window.c = 20; // can be accessed as just c
```

Now, trying to access a non-existing variable throws a *ReferenceError*, while trying to access a non-existing object property just returns undefined.

Interesting fact: [globals created with `var` can't be removed with the `delete` operator](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/), while implicit globals and those created as properties of the global object can.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript (as a core language) does not provide any way to access the object containing all global variables (the *["Global Environment"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.3)*) but it exists nonetheless. In Web browsers, the Global Environment has a variable named `window` (and also `self`, and perhaps `top`) that references the global context.

<sub>*You can type `window.window.self.top.window.top.window.x` if you like. :)*</sub>

Thus, in a context without a local `var x` or `var y` defined, this code

```
x = 42;
window.y = 17;
```

…will assign both variables in the global context, and this code:

```
console.log(window.x);
console.log(y);
```

…will read the values from the global context.

JavaScript (like Lua and Ruby) lets you set the value for a global variable without predefining the variable as global. (Note, however, that [this is disallowed in ECMAScript5 strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).)

However, JavaScript (unlike Lua and Ruby) explicitly **does not allow you to access an unset global variable**. *(See [ECMAScript 5 specification section 8.7.1](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1), step 3.)* It does this to protect you slightly from accidentally reading a global variable when you made a typo. In Lua you can write:

```lua
myLongNamedGlobalVariable = 42   -- assign to a global variable
print(myLongNamedGlobalVeriable) --> nil   (wtf!)
```

and not realize that you've made a typo. In JavaScript, you are protected from this by the ReferenceError.